# ValueError: Shape of passed values is (20453, 769), indices imply (20453, 795)

Tags: pandas, numpy, machine-learning, scikit-learn, data-science

[while I am using simple imputer or KNN imputer, I am getting this error, any idea, why I am getting this and how can i resolve it?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W860z.png)

Comment: Do you use the add_indicator=True option?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

this is solved! there were some columns with all the nan values, so after dropping those columns, it was not throwing the error.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).